# how to set background image in Linear layout dynamically using Parser in android

Tags: java, android

how to set background image in LinearLayout dynamically using Parser in android.
Please help me according the how to set image dynamically.

```
private void createEventCoverPage() {
final EventCoverData currentEventData = mEventData.get(mCurrentIndex);
LinearLayout mParentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.eventCoverParentLayoutId);
                mParentLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),                        Picasso.with(getParent()).load(currentEventData.mImageSrc).get()));
 }      

@Parcel
public static class EventCoverData {
@SerializedName("src")
public String mImageSrc;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to set url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like that

```
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentEventData.mImageSrc).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                 mParentLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });
```